# how can I rest all my customized index at 11pm sharply

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

how can I rest all my customized index **at 11pm sharply**?

below code is not working for me.

my sample

```
A = B + C
D = A[0] + A[1] + A[2]
rest_bar = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 23, 0, 0)
if rest_bar
    A == 0
    D == 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a [mutable variable](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-assignment)

and *rest_bar* must be different from its previous value

Something like that

```
//<set initial values>
A = 0

B = 1
C = 1
A := B + C
D = A[0] + A[1] + A[2]
rest_bar = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 23, 0, 0)
if rest_bar != rest_bar[1]
    A := 0
    D := 0
```